# How 'this' keyword works?

Tags: javascript

I cannot understand what is `bob.setAge = setAge` doing.  Is anybody can explain how it works?

```
var bob = {
    name: "Bob Smith",
    age: 15
};

var frank = {
    name: "Frank Wolf",
    age: 32
};

function setAge(newAge) {
    this.age = newAge;
}

bob.setAge = setAge;
bob.setAge(23);
```

Comment: When you use the debugger and run through the code and inspect those values before and after the debugger hits them, what do you see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `this` will be determined during the time of invocation of the function. So, when you invoke it with `bob` like this

```
bob.setAge(23);
```

inside `setAge`, `this` will refer `bob`. So, `23` will be assigned to `bob`'s `age` attribute.

You can dynamically attach that function to any object and invoke `setAge`. For example,

```
frank.setAge = setAge;
frank.setAge(26);
```

will set the `age` of `frank` to `26`.

**Note :** If you simply invoke the `setAge` function without any object, like this

```
setAge(10);
```

then JavaScript will make sure that the `this` will refer the global object. But if you are executing this in Script mode, `this` will be set to `undefined` and `setAge` will fail. Because, you cannot set `age` on `undefined`.

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: what is script mode?

Answer (score 0):

`bob.setAge = setAge;` `--->`  `bob.setAge` (*like a reference variable*) will now refer to `setAge` function so that you can call it like `bob.setAge(23)` , As you are calling it from bob object. `this` will refer to `bob` inside `setAge` function

Answer (score 0):

basically setAge is just a function. that suppose to alter the value of the property age.

ones you do

```
bob.setAge = setAge;.
```

you add to the object bob the method setAge that will now alter the value of bob's Age.

so now after invoking bob.setAge(23);

the age changes from 15 to 23.